# three.js wireframe only shape with hidden edges as dashed lines

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I'm trying to create a specific type of 3D object in three.js.
I want for example a cube in wireframe mode (so only edges shown).
But I want the edges that are behind to be dashed.
Illustration: [image: illustration]

I don't know if this is feasible with three.js or if I should try directly with webgl.
Should I use `THREE.Mesh` in wireframe or `THREE.Line` with `LineDashedMaterial` or maybe both on top of each other?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I managed to do it.
You need to create three objects.

1st object: the solid 3d object (I mean the faces not the edges)

2nd object: all edges but dashed

3rd object: all edges but normal (not dashed)

For the 1st object set the material with `color: false, side: THREE.DoubleSide, depthTest: true`.

Second object material: `color: (whatever you like), depthTest: false`.

Third object material: `color: (whatever you like), depthTest: true`.

I also set all materials with `polygonOffset: true, polygonOffsetFactor: 1, polygonOffsetUnits: 1` to get rid of z-fighting.

Answer (score 3):

This is a really cool idea. I have implemented your answer as described above at:

http://stemkoski.github.com/Three.js/Dashed-3D.html

in case anybody wants to see it in action.

Comment: this doesn't appear to work anymore. If I understand correctly, the "visible" edges should be the only ones displayed (as solid lines), and the edges that would be covered if the cube's material were displayed should be displayed as dashed lines. Is that correct? In your example, I see a solid cube, with both dashed and solid lines; however, I can only see the front faces because the faces are solid. Did something change with three.js? Or does this render as intended? Given the OPs question, I presume this example does not work (anymore).

Comment: Also, after looking through a few of your demos, I also noticed that the subdivision surface modifier example is ... odd. From the screenshots, I presume that these worked at one time. It might be something with three.js that chagned?

Comment: The link is broken.