# Occluded object with three.js behaving strangely

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

Using the three.js library I managed to show occluded edges of a 3D object as dashed lines.

And I want edges occluded by other objects to behave the same way.

With the solution explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15084165/three-js-wireframe-only-shape-with-hidden-edges-as-dashed-lines) it's working fine except in some strange cases.

Here's an illustration of such a case (I use an orthographic camera so we don't see how far away objects are from each other, hence the text in the picture):
[image]

Has anyone ever encountered something similar?

Any idea why in this case it's not working?

Maybe the part `polygonOffset: true, polygonOffsetFactor: 1, polygonOffsetUnits: 1` in my code is misused.

Or maybe `side: THREE.DoubleSide` in my material is the source of this problem. Because I've seen it has some weird behaviour with transparency.

Here's my code : http://jsfiddle.net/car3v/4/

Comment: Thanks it solved my problem, at least this particular example I showed in jsfiddle.

Comment: I turned my previous comment into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object with the dashed lines with the material's `depthTest: false` has to be in front in case it's occluded by a mesh of a "plain" object.
So I just set manually `dashed_object.renderDepth = 9007199254740992;` which is the biggest integer possible in JavaScript and now it's working properly.